# Where does Adi Shankara use the allegory of water worshipping to the sea?

Tags: worship, adi-shankaracharya

A very famous allegory used by [Adi Shankaracharya](http://www.kamakoti.org/miscl/adi.html) is that he says my worship is like water worshipping to the ocean. Where is it found?

Answer (score 6):

One of the many wonderful compositions of Adi Shankaracharya is the *Soundarya Lahari* (Waves of Beauty). This poem worships *Shakti*, the feminine form of the Divine. At the end of Soundarya Lahari, Adi Shankara says:

[image: Soundarya Lahari]

> Oh Goddess who is the source of all words,
>
> This poem which is made of words,
>
> That you only made,
>
> Is like showing the camphor lamp to the Sun,
>
> Is like offering as ablation to the moon,
>
> The water got from the moon stone,
>
> And is like offering water worship,
>
> To the sea.

References used:

http://shankaracharya.org/soundarya_lahari.php
http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/saundaryalahari.pdf

Comment: Highlighting/mentioning the phrase that refers to the ocean and water would help.